# what does os_atomic_or2o actually do?

Tags: c, gcc, grand-central-dispatch

When I dive into source code of GCD (Grand Central Dispatch), I found some low-level C functions used in `dispatch_block_cancel` showed below

```c
dispatch_block_cancel(dispatch_block_t db)
{
    dispatch_block_private_data_t dbpd = _dispatch_block_get_data(db);
    if (unlikely(!dbpd)) {
        DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(0, "Invalid block object passed to "
                "dispatch_block_cancel()");
    }
    (void)os_atomic_or2o(dbpd, dbpd_atomic_flags, DBF_CANCELED, relaxed);
}
```

The `os_atomic_or2o` macro seems to set `DBF_CANCELED` in `dbpd` which is the private data of the block. 
But after use `gcc -E` expand the macro, I can't find any setting behavior.

```c
(void)({ 
__typeof__(__c11_atomic_load(((__typeof__(*((&(dbpd)->dbpd_atomic_flags))) _Atomic *)((&(dbpd)->dbpd_atomic_flags))), memory_order_relaxed)) _v = (((1u))), 
_r = __c11_atomic_fetch_or(((__typeof__(*((&(dbpd)->dbpd_atomic_flags))) _Atomic *)((&(dbpd)->dbpd_atomic_flags))), _v, memory_order_relaxed);
(__typeof__(_r))(_r | _v); 
});
```

`_v` is a variable inited by type of `&(dbpd)->dbpd_atomic_flags`, value of `1u`.

`_r` is a variable inited by `|` operation between `_v` and `&(dbpd)->dbpd_atomic_flags`.

And finally do an `|` operation and end.
Where is the assigning code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the secret behind the macro `os_atomic_or2o`, the assigning code is `__c11_atomic_fetch_or` which is `__atomic_fetch_or` and in [GCC built_in functions referrence](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), this function will assign new value to the first param.